# How to make video in MATLAB from continous plots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

This is part of the code the makes the video:

```
k = 10000;
j = 1;
v = VideoWriter('myVideo.avi');
open(v)
while j < k
    axis([0 5 0 1000]);
    plot(0:dr:R, u_sol_matrix(:,j))
    frame = getframe(gcf);
    writeVideo(v,frame);
    j = j + 50;
    % pause(0.01)
end
close(v)
```

Now, given a matrix `u_sol_matrix`, where every column represents a solution for a PDE at a certain time point, I plot the solutions and the by the `getframe` command capture these plots and make a movie out of it.

The problem is that the axis keeps changing as the plot keeps adjusting to the solution. I want the axis to be *constant*. How do I get this to work? I have tried adding  `axis` but this does not work apparently.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you're specifying your axis limits before plotting, try changing that.

Comment: It worked! Thank you Adriaan. Can't believe such a minor change made all the difference...

Answer (score 1):

```
k = 10000;
j = 1;
v = VideoWriter('myVideo.avi');
open(v)
while j < k
    fig = figure(); % Explicitly create figure
    plot(0:dr:R, u_sol_matrix(:,j))
    axis([0 5 0 1000]);  % first plot, then change axis
    frame = getframe(gcf);
    writeVideo(v,frame);
    close(fig)  % close figure explicitly.
    j = j + 50;
    % pause(0.01)
end
close(v)
```

Flipping the figure creation and setting axis limits should do the trick. When you call `axis` without an open figure, MATLAB creates one, only to overwrite it if you don't call `hold on`, thus changing the limits to whatever the plot "needs" to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Adriaan answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59179792/7054628), you just have to flip the order of plotting and setting axis limits to make this work.

However, when creating animations, it is faster to first initialize a figure and the graphics objects (i.e. lines, scatter points, etc.), and later update the data in a loop.

```
k = 10000;
j = 1;
v = VideoWriter('myVideo.avi');
open(v)

% some test data
x = 10;
y = sin(1:k);

% init a figure and plot handles
fig = figure(1);
p = plot(x, y(1), 'o'); % create line object, and store the handle
axis([9 11 -1 1]) % axis limits for test data

% update data during animation
while j < k
    p.XData = x;       % update X and Y data properties of line object
    p.YData = y(j); 
    frame = getframe(gcf);
    writeVideo(v,frame);
    j = j + 50;
    pause(0.01)
end
close(v)
```

Since you don't have to create a new line primitive each loop iteration, this will save a lot of time. You only have to adjust the X and Y data properties of the already existing line, which has considerable less overhead.